# Do IBIS signal names need to be unique?

Tags: eda

I don't see any reference in the [specification](http://eda.org/pub/ibis/ver5.0/ver5_0.pdf) that says so, but then I don't see anything that says otherwise.  Other sections do talk about uniqueness, so I'm guessing they don't need to be unique.

EDIT: 2/18/11: I'm using Mentor's HyperLynx simulation software.

Comment: Your spec link doesn't work...

Comment: remove the / at the end of the url and it will bring it up till he can fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spoke to Mentor support.  They make the HyperLynx family of tools.  They confirmed they need not be unique.  Use the parser to verify your IBIS models; which I did and it didn't complain.  Also they are not shorted even if they have the same name.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for getting the correct information. I'll dabble more carefully next time.